# Difference between if(isset(a,b)) and if(isset(a) && isset(b))

Tags: php

As mentioned in the title, What is the difference between using

```
if(isset($a, $b)){
    //execute...
}
```

And

```
if(isset($a) && isset($b)){
    //execute...
}
```

And which one is better in your opinion?

Comment: None and neither.

Comment: No different, But neither of them you prefer?

Comment: I have no preference.

Comment: @JayBlanchard But there is no difference at all between the two methods except for flexibility?

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: well one example relies on isset's internal logic to test all the variables, and the other one relies on your boolean logic to test the outcomes of each call to isset. That's the difference. Since isset likely uses exactly the same logic internally, there's no difference in the output. It's straightforward to prove that by testing it, of course. Arguably, the first version is a bit less verbose, and also relies on already-proven and tested logic, whereas the second version relies on you writing the correct boolean logic. So personally I'd prefer the first version, but it's purely an opinion.

Comment: Obviously if you want to vary it and use an "or" or something, then you'd need the second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference if you plan on using `empty()` later on, instead of `isset()`.

The `isset()` does allow for comma separated values, while `empty()` does not.

Therefore, you will need to use separate conditions on `empty()`, should this be the case at a future date.

But to answer this, there is no difference; both are valid and work the same way.

> And which one is better in your opinion?

That's purely by preference.

However, if one or another should fail, then check for both in separate conditions. Both need to be set in order for `isset()` to work when using this method `if(isset($a, $b))`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in php [isset documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only
> if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right
> and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

So there is no difference in functionality.

I personally prefer the first notion as it produces a slightly shorter code.

Comment: *Yep,* always best to quote the *official* manual ;-)